# Java: get string value regardless of case sensitivity in switch-case

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, equality

i have a some strings(String result) that user inserted it in app without any case-sensitivity policy user can insert such as : "fail" or "Fail" or "FAIL" and "Success" or "success" and etc . and also i have just one method for each of them like : fail() , success() and must call related method

now i want use a one string into switch-case statement by use below constants(success,fail,...) :

```
  public final class ActionResultStatus
{
    public static final String SUCCESS = "Success";
    public static final String FAIL = "Fail";
    public static final String REJECTED = "Rejected";
    public static final String IN_PROGRESS = "InProgress";
}

String result = userClass.getResult(); //UserClass  is a container class for user inputted data
switch(result)
{
case ActionResultStatus.FAIL:
  fail();

case ActionResultStatus.SUCCESS :
  success();
}
```

**Note that's :**

1-i dont want use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` for result because i must add more case statements .

2-i cant change my Constatn class field value to lowerCase they must be pascal-case like:"Success" because they must will be persist on DB exactly in pascal-case mode

3-and i think i couldn't use `equalIgnoreCase()` method for this situation because this isn't if-statement .

Thnak You.

Comment: Very difficult to find a solution with all those constraints, why don't you use a `if-statement` instead of a `switch` ?

Comment: `String result = userClass.getResult().toUpperCase();`

Comment: @user15358848 You're right and I got aware soon enough. But just removing the characters obviously didn't delete the comment. But now it seems to have gone.

Comment: @yassin-hajaj i dont want use if because i very heard if-statement reduce performance , exactly when you use if  more . is it true?

Answer (score 3):

Separate the logic out a bit.  First turn your statuses into and Enum that has a lookup function to find the enum:

```
public enum ActionResultStatus {
    SUCCESS("Success"),
    FAIL("Fail"),
    REJECTED("Rejected"),
    IN_PROGESS("InProgress"),
    UNKNOWN("Unknown");
    
    private String outputStr;
    
    private ActionResultStatus(String output) {
        outputStr = output; 
    }
    
    public static ActionResultStatus findStatus(String input) {
        for (ActionResultStatus status : values()) {
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(status.outputStr)) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return outputStr;
    }
}
```

Then your processing logic become something like:

```
ActionResultStatus status = ActionResultStatus.findStatus(userClass.getResult());
switch (status) {
    case FAIL:  fail(); break;
    case SUCCESS: success(); break;
    default: break;
}
```